# Compile PythonTeX using TexPad editor

Tags: compiling, pythontex, texpad, macos

I recently started using PythonTeX, but am struggling to streamline my workflow. I use the latest version of TexPad (Version 1.9.2) under macOS Mojave. I'm perfectly capable of compiling PythonTeX (v. 0.16) on my machine using Terminal, but I would like to use TexPad to do the building process for me. I use the following (official) PythonTeX .tpbuild script.

```
#!/bin/bash
# Texpad build (.tpbuild) file to use PythonTeX within Texpad
# NB this is to demonstrate pythontex only, it would need alterations to support bibliographies, indices, etc.

pdflatex -synctex=1 "$TEXPAD_ROOTFILE"
pythontex "$TEXPAD_ROOTFILE_NO_EXT"
pdflatex -synctex=1 "$TEXPAD_ROOTFILE"
```

which can be found [here](https://github.com/vallettaventures/TexpadKB/blob/master/tpbuild-scripts/PythonTeX.tpbuild). However, if I try to compile a PythonTeX document, for example

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pythontex}
\begin{document}
    2+2=\py{2+2}
\end{document}
```

inside texpad I get the following errors.

```
This is TexpadTeX (based on TeX Version 3.14159265 with e-TeX extensions) running in extended mode embedded in Texpad 623 (preloaded format=latex 2021.3.29)  30 JUN 2021 08:15
**
(testII.tex
LaTeX2e <2017-04-15>
Babel <3.16> and hyphenation patterns for 84 language(s) loaded.
(article.cls
Document Class: article 2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
(size10.clo
File: size10.clo 2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX file (size option)
)
\c@part=\count79
\c@section=\count80
\c@subsection=\count81
\c@subsubsection=\count82
\c@paragraph=\count83
\c@subparagraph=\count84
\c@figure=\count85
\c@table=\count86
\abovecaptionskip=\skip41
\belowcaptionskip=\skip42
\bibindent=\dimen102
)

! LaTeX Error: File `pythontex.sty' not found.

Type X to quit or <RETURN> to proceed,
or enter new name. (Default extension: sty)

Enter file name: 
! Emergency stop.
<read *> 
         
l.3 \begin
          {document}^^M
*** (cannot \read from terminal in nonstop modes)

No pages of output.


This is TexpadTeX (based on TeX Version 3.14159265 with e-TeX extensions) running in extended mode embedded in Texpad 623 (preloaded format=latex 2021.3.29)  30 JUN 2021 08:15
**
(testII.tex
LaTeX2e <2017-04-15>
Babel <3.16> and hyphenation patterns for 84 language(s) loaded.
(article.cls
Document Class: article 2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
(size10.clo
File: size10.clo 2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX file (size option)
)
\c@part=\count79
\c@section=\count80
\c@subsection=\count81
\c@subsubsection=\count82
\c@paragraph=\count83
\c@subparagraph=\count84
\c@figure=\count85
\c@table=\count86
\abovecaptionskip=\skip41
\belowcaptionskip=\skip42
\bibindent=\dimen102
)

! LaTeX Error: File `pythontex.sty' not found.

Type X to quit or <RETURN> to proceed,
or enter new name. (Default extension: sty)

Enter file name: 
! Emergency stop.
<read *> 
         
l.3 \begin
          {document}^^M
*** (cannot \read from terminal in nonstop modes)

No pages of output.
```

It would be awesome if someone of you could tell me what I am doing wrong or why the compilation is failing.
Thank you!

Comment: you haven't shown which command is undefined so hard to comment. (show the errors from the log file as text, not an image,

Comment: `"$TEXPAD_ROOTFILE"` should be just the filename not a path, cd to the directory with the file first so that the pythontex files get generated where tex can find them